# assistance with my website pleaase!!! - nav/links in html5 -

Tags: html, css, coding-style, href, nav

I'm coding a website for class and I'm trying to add links to each page with a navigation bar. We use cPanel, so I have all of my pages uploaded correctly...or I think I do anyways.

But my question is: When I type in my code to the address bar it takes me to each page (i.e. index, services, contact us, about us, etc.) but when I go to click on the button on the actual page (i.e. on the home page I click to go to the services page) it comes up as a "Not Found" page and in the address bar it has added quotations around the page link (i.e. on the home page I click the services and in the address bar it has my website link the "service.html") how can I remove the quotations?

Here is my home page (index):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <header><img src="img/sashaemblem.jpg" alt="Hair by Sasha Logo"><h1>Hair by Sasha</h1>
    </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
             <li><a href=”index.html” class=”current”>Home</a></li>
             <li><a href=”services.html”>Services</a></li>
             <li><a href=”aboutus.html”>About Us</a></li>
             <li><a href=”contactus.html”>Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <p> Call for an Appointment with a Sasha's Hair Artist (312) 555-5550 Monday-Friday 10:00-8:00 Saturday 10:00-600</p>
    <footer>
    <p>Cutting edge style at starving artists prices! &copy; 2012 by Hair by Sasha. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: hey ” is not " try to edit your href=”index.html” to href="index.html"

Comment: ohhh okay, thank you! Ive been wracking my brain trying to figure that out, thank you!

Comment: fixed it up like a champ, thanks Mat!

Comment: Anytimes! don't forget to mark your question as answered. have a nice day!